# Calculate a geometric progression

Tags: r

I'm using brute force right now..

```
x <- 1.03
Value <- c((1/x)^20,(1/x)^19,(1/x)^18,(1/x)^17,(1/x)^16,(1/x)^15,(1/x)^14,(1/x)^13,(1/x)^12,(1/x)^11,(1/x)^10,(1/x)^9,(1/x)^8,(1/x)^7,(1/x)^6,(1/x)^5,(1/x)^4,(1/x)^3,(1/x)^2,(1/x),1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5,x^6,x^7,x^8,x^9,x^10,x^11,x^12,x^13,x^14,x^15,x^16,x^17,x^18,x^19,x^20)
Value
```

but I would like to use an increment loop just like the for loop in java

```
for(integer I = 1; I<=20; I++)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`^` is a vectorized function in R. That means you can simply use `x^(-20:20)`.

**Edit because this gets so many upvotes:**

More precisely, both the base parameter and the exponent parameter are vectorized.

You can do this:

```
x <- 1:3
x^2
#[1] 1 4 9
```

and this:

```
2^x
#[1] 2 4 8
```

and even this:

```
x^x
#[1]  1  4 27
```

In the first two examples the length-one parameter gets recycled to match the length of the longer parameter. Thats why the following results in a warning:

```
y <- 1:2
x^y
#[1] 1 4 3
#Warning message:
#  In x^y : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

If you try something like that, you probably want what `outer` can give you:

```
outer(x, y, "^")
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    2    4
#[3,]    3    9
```

Answer (score 1):

Roland already addressed the fact that you can do this vectorized, so I will focus on the loop part in cases where you are doing something more that is not vectorized.

A Java (and C, C++, etc.) style loop like you show is really just a while loop.  Something that you would like to do as:

```
for(I=1, I<=20, I++) { ... }
```

is really just a different way to write:

```
I=1 # or better I <- 1
while( I <= 20 ) {
  ...
  I <- I + 1
}
```

So you already have the tools to do that type of loop.  However if you want to assign the results into a vector, matrix, array, list, etc. and each iteration is independent (does not rely on the previous computation) then it is usually easier, clearer, and overall better to use the `lapply` or `sapply` functions.

Comment: I'm not sure why you show a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop. I need an R `while` loop less than once a year.

Comment: @Roland, because the part of the question that I was answering (at least my interpretation of it) is about a loop that increments a counter until it stops meeting a condition rather than iterating over a prespecified set of values.  The R `for` loop does the later, the `while` loop does the former.